# How do I install crash 5.1.6 on 11.04?

Tags: apt, partial-upgrade

I am running i386 (32-bit) natty, and have installed crash, but it doesn't work on the running system.  I found the solution on the crash author's page -- the problem was fixed in 5.1.6 and I have 5.0.7 -- but I can't find a way to upgrade crash to 5.1.6 using either synaptic or apt-get.

The machine in question does not have Internet access, so I've downloaded crash_5.1.6-1ubuntu1_i386.deb onto a flash drive (using a different machine) and mounted it on the machine where I need the upgrade.  However, when I try to install it, apt-get claims that it can't find the package.  (I've tried many variations on this, and also tried using synaptic; and yes, I'm aware that the "-s" will keep it from actually doing anything -- I want to be sure of what-all it will do before letting it do it -- but shouldn't it still find the file?)

```
$ uname -a
Linux tester-2012-Client-Platform 3.2.12 #3 SMP Fri Jul 6 14:34:59 PDT 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
$ (cd /media/16FB-E6BB/pkg && ll crash_5.1.6* && sudo apt-get -s -V --no-download -u install crash=5.1.6 )
-r--r--r-- 1 tester tester 2277846 2011-06-17 01:05 crash_5.1.6-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '5.1.6' for 'crash' was not found
```

As shown by the "ll" output, the file does exist.  How do I get apt-get to see it?

Comment: You cannot use that deb because it's for 11.10/Oneiric, not for Natty. The highest version officially released for Natty is the buggy 5.0.7 you have.

Sorry, but you'll have to build from source, or find a PPA.

Comment: Or you remove the old crash, search all the dependencies and their dependencies in the package search for precise, download them for precise, install them and after a long and tedious session of manual `.deb` installation you'll really appreciate aptitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to just double click the .deb file? That should install it using Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: It had not occurred to me to try that previously.  (I'm quite new to Ubuntu.)  It looks as if it may have worked, at least there's no error message.

Comment: That seems to have worked, and the original problem (not recognizing the kernel image as matching the running system) is fixed, but now "crash" reports a "read error" when asked to display the contents of a kernel virtual address that is known to be valid.  Any idea (or is there a different way to examine kernel memory)?